# Split VPN on IIS Server

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, dns, iis

I have a very complex (At least I think it is) issue to work around.

**The problem**

I have an AWS Elastic Beanstalk server running Windows Server 2012 and IIS.
This server has a dynamically created network adapter from the AWS setup and a public IP address.

This IIS server is hosting a C# web API that needs to communicate with a locally hosted database and other AWS databases.

The local business has a VPN, when I configure this VPN on the AWS server (As expected) the server falls off the air. Can't be pinged or published too.

**The question**

This there some scheme that would allow tagging to happen, so when for instance I hit a DNS of locally_"hostname" windows would know to route that via the VPN while all other traffic goes via the standard adapter.

Or I am even willing to go the other way, only put a port or so via the standard adapter, enough to let me remote to it and 80 and 8080 for the API to keep functioning correctly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am a bit confused by your question. What do you mean by "(As expected) the server falls off the air." Can you be more specific what problem you are having? You can, of course, control the routing table of your VPC and specify exactly what IP addresses will be sent over the tunnel.

Comment: It sounds to me like the VPN is publishing a default route, rather then only routes to the addresses of the business.

Comment: When I meant by falls off the air, once the VPN is connected the public IP and URL can no longer be used to connect to the AWS server. It sounds like the routing table idea is the best way around it, I am just unsure how to start.